# SWT getText() from Text widget returning NULL string

Tags: java, eclipse, events, swt, listener

This SWT program has a Group called mBuy, which includes Text Field to enter a stock's buy price. Once the calculate button is pressed and event listener is activated, I want to assign whatever content is inside this text field to a variable, which I have initialized here.

```
final Text tmp0 = new Text(mBuy, SWT.SINGLE);
tmp0.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

// Calculate Button
Button tmp3 = new Button(mBuy, SWT.PUSH);
tmp3.setText("Calculate");
tmp3.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, true));

// if calculate button is pressed
tmp3.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        //take the decimal value inside textbox 
        bPrice=Double.parseDouble(tmp0.getText());
        // don't show buy menu anymore
        mBuy.dispose();

    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried adding debug to see that tmp0 is not null and tmp0.getText() is null?  getText() would normally only return null before the Text control has been properly created and displayed, but since you are responding to a button press it is hard to see how this could be the case?

Comment: Please add the stacktrace...